# Highslide - margins of html popup and picture [highslide]

Tags: highslide

I am using two `slideshowGroups` in the same page: one is for pictures (gallery) and one is for html (in iframe) only. How to set different margins for each?

I need to have `marginBottom` = about 80px and `marginLeft` = about 200px for pictures, to give space for specifically designed controls, but html-s should be centered vertically and horizontally.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set `hs.align = 'center';` as global setting for both slideshowGroup. This will center both `slideshowGroup` regardless what margins you are using.
Default margins for all sides are 15. I don’t know the name of the `slideshowGroup` for your gallery, but say it’s `'gallery'` – add this to your settings (requires highslide-full.js):

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onInit = function () {
    hs.marginBottom = (this.slideshowGroup == 'gallery') ? 80 : 15;
    hs.marginLeft = (this.slideshowGroup == 'gallery') ? 200 : 15;
};
```